# Directive or parameter "Check" expression error: Can only call function "ExpandConstant" within parameter lists

Tags: inno-setup

I have this in my `[ISPP]` section:

```
; Help Documentation download URL
#define HelpDocSetupURL "https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/downloads/PublicTalksHelpDocumentationSetup.exe"
```

I have this in my `[FILES]` section:

```
Source: "{tmp}\HelpDocSetup.exe"; \
    DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: external deleteafterinstall; \
    Tasks: downloadhelp; \
    Check: DwinsHs_Check( ExpandConstant('{tmp}\HelpDocSetup.exe'), {#HelpDocSetupURL}, 'My_Setup', 'Get', 0, 0 )
```

When I compile I get an error:

> Line 441: Directive or parameter "Check" expression error: Can only call function "ExpandConstant" within parameter lists.

I can use the literal path but how can I use my #define?

---

### Update

- I understand that `{#HelpDocSetupURL}` is emitting a preprocessor directive and as a result is only known at compile time (which is correct).
- I also understand that the error says "Directive or parameter "Check" expression error: Can **only call** function **"ExpandConstant"** within **parameter lists**."

Thus we are not allowed to use a preprocessor directive in this context. At the moment I am using the literal path instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you get is confusing.

After preprocessor you will get this code:

```
Check: DwinsHs_Check( ExpandConstant('{tmp}\HelpDocSetup.exe'), https://www.example.com/downloads/PublicTalksHelpDocumentationSetup.exe, 'My_Setup', 'Get', 0, 0 )
```

What is clearly a syntax error. The code misses quotes.

You want this:

```
Check: DwinsHs_Check( ExpandConstant('{tmp}\HelpDocSetup.exe'), '{#HelpDocSetupURL}', ...)
```

Comment: Doh! How silly of me! I will test later when on the PC! 